# django-admin-tools Raises ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin-tools

I installed and configured as told in [quickstart guide](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) of django-admin-tools. Those are `settings.py` lines:

```
# INSTALLED APPS
'admin_tools',
'admin_tools.theming',
'admin_tools.menu',
'admin_tools.dashboard',
'django.contrib.sites',
```

And I also included `admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader` into `TEMPLATES` variable as told in guide as below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

However, it still raises `ImproperlyConfigured` exception as below:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You must add the "admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader" template loader to your TEMPLATES settings variable
```

I did not understand.

## Environment

- python 3.4.x
- django 1.8.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have added it to the list of context processors, you should have added it to the list of loaders instead:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

See the [documentation for `DjangoTemplates`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) for more information about each `OPTION`.